# how to use db2look command with java

Tags: java, spring-boot, db2, schema

I am using db2 database and i want to get ddl(data definition language) of all objects like table,function,view etc.

i am using db2look command  in DB2 command window and it was working correctly and i am getting schema of all objects. Command is:-

```
db2look -d sample -a -e -x -o fileout.txt
```

Now i am creating java application in which i want to execute following command but it was not working :-

```
 connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
         stmt = connection.createStatement();
          rs = stmt.executeQuery("execute db2look -d sample a -e -x -o FIlE_OUT.txt");
```

**For example we can use ddlgen command to get ddl in syabse and we can use it with java . Same in db2 database i want use db2look command**

So please suggest how i can use db2look command with java.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do this if Java is running on the same hostname where the db2look executable runs.  The actual database can be remote if you have catalogued it and supply credentials on the db2look command-line, and if the credentials have correct authorisation on the database.

To run db2look, use your preferred method for executing external programs from java. It is a frequently asked question "run an external program from java" so start your research.

Your code sample is incorrect because db2look *is not SQL*, it is an external command. You cannot use `executeQuery` for an external command.

Take a look at the many pages that describe options for running external commands from java for example at [here](https://www.quickprogrammingtips.com/java/how-to-run-external-program-in-java.html).

Comment: I am using same machine where java and db2 both are installed